# webrtc disconnected on proximity sensor off screen

Tags: android, webrtc, proximitysensor

we have an android application that uses webrtc for p2p call.
currently on some phones, when the call is answered and proximity sensor causes screen turns off, then after about 7 seconds onIceConnectionChange fired with disconnected event.
How can I prevent this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: Please check and confirm if your issue relate to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=951418